# Get the value of the last inserted record

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to get the `stop_name` of the last inserted row in the table with preparedStatement. How can I get the last inserted one?

I appreciate any help.

**behavoiur table:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS behaviour(
    behaviour_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    mac VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    stop_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    stop_distance INT(11) NOT NULL,
    speed INT(11) NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Comment: Are you asking help with writing the query or writing the code?

Comment: With writing the query

Comment: Which db are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this query:

```
select stop_name from behaviour where created_at in (select max(created_at) from behaviour)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
select stop_name from behaviour order by behaviour_id desc limit 1;
```